# Returning an extended matrix with apply

Tags: r, apply

I have a matrix that that I am trying to use apply on, however my function takes a 10x1 matrix and then returns a 10x2 matrix (ie calaculates 2 values for each inout value).  My overall dataframe is 10x3 so when I use `apply()` I should get a 10x6 matrix, however I can't get `apply()` to add more columns, is this possible with `apply()`?  My function produces a 10x2 but the second column ges cut off when I call `apply()`.

```
data_matrix <- function(column) {
  polynomial <- poly(column, degree=2, raw=TRUE)
  return(polynomial)
}
poly_matrix <- apply(test_data, 2, data_matrix)
```

Comment: Using test_data <- matrix(1:30, nrow =10, ncol = 3), I get  dim(poly_matrix) [1] 20  3, so you want the results, currently poly_matrix[11:20, 1:3] , to be interleaved? In any case you don't need apply as poly(test_data, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)[1:10, c(1:3, 5:6, 9)] in the raw = TRUE case, seems the result you're describing. Sharing your test_data and expected results would help clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Have `apply` not simplify its output. This is done by calling it with argument `simplify` set to `FALSE`.
An alternative is to use `lapply` directly but this is only possible if the input is a data.frame, if the input data is of class `"matrix"` then you will have to use `apply`.

```r
data_matrix <- function(column) {
  polynomial <- poly(column, degree = 2L, raw = TRUE)
  polynomial
}

# make the input data and the results reproducible
set.seed(2023)
# test data
test_data <- replicate(3L, rnorm(5L)) |> as.data.frame()

# change argument 'simplify' default to get a list,
# then cbind the list members to form a matrix
poly_matrix <- apply(test_data, 2L, data_matrix, simplify = FALSE)
do.call(cbind, poly_matrix)
#>                1           2          1         2          1         2
#> [1,] -0.08378436 0.007019818  1.0907975 1.1898391  0.3269621 0.1069042
#> [2,] -0.98294375 0.966178406 -0.9137273 0.8348975 -0.4127469 0.1703600
#> [3,] -1.87506732 3.515877460  1.0016397 1.0032821  0.5620365 0.3158850
#> [4,] -0.18614466 0.034649835 -0.3992666 0.1594138  0.6633583 0.4400442
#> [5,] -0.63348570 0.401304130 -0.4681231 0.2191392 -0.6028973 0.3634851


# lapply returns a list of the matrices output by the called function
poly_matrix <- lapply(test_data, data_matrix)
do.call(cbind, poly_matrix)
#>                1           2          1         2          1         2
#> [1,] -0.08378436 0.007019818  1.0907975 1.1898391  0.3269621 0.1069042
#> [2,] -0.98294375 0.966178406 -0.9137273 0.8348975 -0.4127469 0.1703600
#> [3,] -1.87506732 3.515877460  1.0016397 1.0032821  0.5620365 0.3158850
#> [4,] -0.18614466 0.034649835 -0.3992666 0.1594138  0.6633583 0.4400442
#> [5,] -0.63348570 0.401304130 -0.4681231 0.2191392 -0.6028973 0.3634851


# a pipe to do.call will do any of the above in one code line only
apply(test_data, 2L, data_matrix, simplify = FALSE) |> do.call(cbind, args = _)
#>                1           2          1         2          1         2
#> [1,] -0.08378436 0.007019818  1.0907975 1.1898391  0.3269621 0.1069042
#> [2,] -0.98294375 0.966178406 -0.9137273 0.8348975 -0.4127469 0.1703600
#> [3,] -1.87506732 3.515877460  1.0016397 1.0032821  0.5620365 0.3158850
#> [4,] -0.18614466 0.034649835 -0.3992666 0.1594138  0.6633583 0.4400442
#> [5,] -0.63348570 0.401304130 -0.4681231 0.2191392 -0.6028973 0.3634851

lapply(test_data, data_matrix) |> do.call(cbind, args = _)
#>                1           2          1         2          1         2
#> [1,] -0.08378436 0.007019818  1.0907975 1.1898391  0.3269621 0.1069042
#> [2,] -0.98294375 0.966178406 -0.9137273 0.8348975 -0.4127469 0.1703600
#> [3,] -1.87506732 3.515877460  1.0016397 1.0032821  0.5620365 0.3158850
#> [4,] -0.18614466 0.034649835 -0.3992666 0.1594138  0.6633583 0.4400442
#> [5,] -0.63348570 0.401304130 -0.4681231 0.2191392 -0.6028973 0.3634851
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

After reading the documentation more carefully it seems that this behavior of `apply` is a design decision. The documentation first refers to functions returning vectors. Quoting from [`help("apply")`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/apply.html), section Value, my emphasis.

> If each call to `FUN` returns a **vector of length `n`**, and `simplify` is TRUE, then apply returns an array of dimension `c(n, dim(X)[MARGIN])` if `n > 1`. If `n` equals 1, apply returns a vector if `MARGIN` has length 1 and an array of dimension `dim(X)[MARGIN]` otherwise. If `n` is 0, the result has length 0 but not necessarily the ‘correct’ dimension.

Then, in the last paragraph it reads, my emphasis:

> In all cases the result is **coerced by [`as.vector`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/vector.html) to one of the basic vector types before the dimensions are set**, so that (for example) factor results will be coerced to a character array.

This explains why the call with the default `simplify = TRUE` returns a matrix with `dim[1L]` double the length of the input vectors. All attributes are removed from the result if it is of an atomic mode by `as.vector`. This is the case with numeric matrices, they are atomic vectors with a `dim` attribute and therefore removed, becoming vectors `ncol` times the length (twice, in the question's case).

Answer (score 0):

If you'd use `sapply` you could simply re-arrange the `array` by the old dimensions multiplied by `c(1, deg)`.

```
> deg <- 2
> sapply(dat, poly, degree=deg, raw=TRUE) |> array(dim=dim(dat)*c(1, deg))
            [,1]        [,2]       [,3]      [,4]       [,5]      [,6]
[1,] -0.08378436 0.007019818  1.0907975 1.1898391  0.3269621 0.1069042
[2,] -0.98294375 0.966178406 -0.9137273 0.8348975 -0.4127469 0.1703600
[3,] -1.87506732 3.515877460  1.0016397 1.0032821  0.5620365 0.3158850
[4,] -0.18614466 0.034649835 -0.3992666 0.1594138  0.6633583 0.4400442
[5,] -0.63348570 0.401304130 -0.4681231 0.2191392 -0.6028973 0.3634851
```

Wrapped into a function

```
> extend <- \(dat, deg=2) {
+   sapply(as.data.frame(dat), poly, degree=deg, raw=TRUE) |> 
+     array(dim=dim(dat)*c(1, deg))
+ }
> 
> extend(dat)
            [,1]        [,2]       [,3]      [,4]       [,5]      [,6]
[1,] -0.08378436 0.007019818  1.0907975 1.1898391  0.3269621 0.1069042
[2,] -0.98294375 0.966178406 -0.9137273 0.8348975 -0.4127469 0.1703600
[3,] -1.87506732 3.515877460  1.0016397 1.0032821  0.5620365 0.3158850
[4,] -0.18614466 0.034649835 -0.3992666 0.1594138  0.6633583 0.4400442
[5,] -0.63348570 0.401304130 -0.4681231 0.2191392 -0.6028973 0.3634851
```

Note that `apply` is designed for matrices and, in contrast to `lapply; sapply; vapply`, is slow for data frames.

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(V1 = c(-0.0837843554981313, -0.982943745280687, 
-1.8750673214048, -0.186144660710734, -0.63348569815203), V2 = c(1.09079746414669, 
-0.913727274142924, 1.00163971155077, -0.399266603219373, -0.468123054013521
), V3 = c(0.32696208288009, -0.41274689835186, 0.562036469443693, 
0.663358259979942, -0.602897283941171)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Having agreed data, I'd keep this around for the future to remind myself of what was going on prior to all the wrapping

```
poly_res = poly(as.matrix(dat), degree = 2, raw = TRUE)[1:5, c(1:3, 5:6, 9)]
> dimnames(poly_res) <- list(NULL, 1:6)
> poly_res
               1           2          3         4          5         6
[1,] -0.08378436 0.007019818  1.0907975 1.1898391  0.3269621 0.1069042
[2,] -0.98294375 0.966178406 -0.9137273 0.8348975 -0.4127469 0.1703600
[3,] -1.87506732 3.515877460  1.0016397 1.0032821  0.5620365 0.3158850
[4,] -0.18614466 0.034649835 -0.3992666 0.1594138  0.6633583 0.4400442
[5,] -0.63348570 0.401304130 -0.4681231 0.2191392 -0.6028973 0.3634851
```

data

```
dat = structure(list(V1 = c(-0.0837843554981313, -0.982943745280687, 
-1.8750673214048, -0.186144660710734, -0.63348569815203), V2 = c(1.09079746414669, 
-0.913727274142924, 1.00163971155077, -0.399266603219373, -0.468123054013521
), V3 = c(0.32696208288009, -0.41274689835186, 0.562036469443693, 
0.663358259979942, -0.602897283941171)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-5L))
```

I think the above answers are terrific, but mask what poly did that was close to your desired result (with additional, undesired output) providing an opportunity to select desired results from its output. Returning to this question a year hence, I might fail to recall poly was doing the heavy lifting.